# Why is black (0, 0, 0) the default color of transparency?

Tags: colors, transparency, microsoft-paint

I like to make [my masks](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/358936/suggestions-for-winter-bash-2021/359100#359100) and I always notice something funny. Whenever I paste a transparent image on MS Paint (not sure what version), the transparent colors are always the default black (0, 0, 0).

For example, pasting the Stack Overflow logo from its [tour page](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) results to this:

[image: Black Background]

Why is black usually the default color in MS Paint? How do I change the default color?

Comment: I'd be looking for a better graphic editor. Paint is obviously just not up to the task. If you open that in Photoshop there is 'no colour' at all, it remains perfectly transparent. Gimp & Paint.net are freeware, both ought to be a significant improvement over MS Paint.

Comment: @Tetsujin Cool, now I got a new editor to use to make these masks, but making sure to retain the original mask sizes will be something I have to learn.

Comment: I'm not particularly familiar with either of the apps I recommended - I use Photoshop myself - but any decent package ought to be able to just paste the logo in as a separate layer, keeping all the transparency intact. It is what I would consider a 'basic requirement' for a graphics package.

Answer (score 1):

The black has something to do with the transparency. If something is transparent, there is no color given, so Paint must've chosen (0, 0, 0) because there's no given color whatsoever.

The way to remove the default black in the images is to change Color 2 to (0, 0, 0) and the result from the previous image will be:

[image: White Transparency]

There's still some black, and that's because the black doesn't match with the default. If we want other colors to be used to replace the black however, we unfortunately still don't know how.